# Dynamically join from view to key-value table in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, dynamic-linq

In my project, I have one regular table in form of a view. Let's call it `BaseView`. Another table `KeyValueTable` contains three columns: `ID_BaseView`, `Key` and `Value`.

Joining them together in SQL is quite simple:

```sql
SELECT
  bv.ID,
  bv.Data1,
  bv.Data2,
  kvt1.Value AS SomeKeyData,
  kvt2.Value AS SomeOtherKeyData
FROM BaseView bv
INNER JOIN KeyValueTable kvt1
  ON kvt1.ID_BaseView = bv.ID
  AND kvt1.Key = 'SomeKey'
INNER JOIN KeyValueTable kvt2
  ON kvt2.ID_BaseView = bv.ID
  AND kvt2.Key = 'SomeOtherKey'
```

In my project, I need to dynamically join those together. I already have an `IQueryable<BaseView>` with a where string attached. Another table `ClientColumns` contains a list of all keys of the key value table, that must be joined for this client. Reading those column names is done by some c# code already. So I basically end up with my `IQueryable<BaseView>` and a `string[]` of distinct keys.

Now, how can I use Linq's `Join` method (or any other method) to dynamically join those queries together?

```cs
IQueryable<BaseView> bv = GenerateBaseViewQuery();
string[] clientColumns = GetClientColumns();
string[] requiredKeys = GetClientKeys();
IQueryable finalResult = bv;

foreach (string key in requiredKeys) {
    finalResult = finalResult.Join(/* What to enter here? */);
}

return finalResult.Select($"new ({string.Join(",", clientColumns)})");
```

Or is there even a better approach?

By the way, I'm using Dynamic LINQ for the final select, so don't wonder why there is this strange syntax in the final `Select` statement.

Comment: do You need to be using dynamic-linq?  it is pretty easy to solve on the entity framework context level, it seems like you're wanting to solve the problem too far up the stack

Comment: @T.Nielsen Yes, it is a requirement. The database view I'm accessing has a few hundred columns, and I only want to select a few. But I already found a solution in the mean time without using a join statement.

Comment: Great! Why not close the question then and if really generous, post the solution to help anyone coming here with a similar problem